Modeling the body of a character
I am trying to model Domo in blender but am having issues figuring out how to create the body shape, specifically the curved area at the bottom where the legs sit. What would be the easist way in making the body of this character?


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
